# Does the SynchronizationContext is used only for WPF,Win forms?

Tags: c#, synchronizationcontext

Each article i read about SynchronizationContext talks on dealing with the form's controls.
Is it the only purpose of the SynchronizationContext?

And I have to ask a basic thing also: Why cant I just do a lock on each control befor i use if the UI thread use it? why i need all this "SynchronizationContext" to communicate with the controls? I mean, isnt it a better way to communicate the controls? (I know it wont work).

**Articles:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx

http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/18/parallelism-in-net-part-15-making-tasks-run-the-taskscheduler/

..

Comment: I don't see any relation b/w lock and `SynchronizationContext` What do you mean by this `Why cant I just do a lock on each control befor i use if the UI thread use it? why i need all this "SynchronizationContext"`?

Comment: if the SynchronizationContext provied me a thread-safe way to communicate with the controls, i can do a simple lock insted. Am I right?

Comment: Nope, lock is implemented based on `Monitor` class which ensures only one thread can execute critical section of a code at a time. whereas `SynchronizationContext` is used to execute some code in context of another thread or same. Typically we use `SynchronizationContext` to execute code in another thread(UI thread typically). Is this clear?

Comment: almost, what other uses the SynchronizationContext has? why would i want to stop the running of a thread for aother code that aother thread told him to run? and u didnt answer what i adked, (i know it doesnt work that way..)

Comment: Could you pls eloborate *i know it doesnt work that way.*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SynchronizationContext can be used to execute work in any other thread's context.

There is a main caveat here though: the other thread needs to be prepared for that, e. g. by using a message pump, like the UI threads in WinForm and WPF do. Also, those UI threads always have a SynchronizationContext, while other thread types typically don't.

As for locking as an alternative, that would need a completely different design inside Microsoft classes. It might be possible, though it might also result in threads blocking for a long time when waiting. I think it would open a lot of possibilities for misuse.

[This article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I) is rather helpful, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/4107653/586754.